# Vue3, Pinia, laravel : Array of object loses its last element when copied in the store

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I use vuejs/quasar and pinia for a spa with laravel 10 as backend.

At app start up I fetch data from the backend this way

```
let everything = null;
async function fetchEverything() {
  //fetch user in backend
  let res = await authStore.fetchUser();
  if (res === "success" && authStore.authUser !== null) {
    everything = await axios.get("api/everything");
    
    //THE PART THAT HAS ISSUE
    console.log(everything.data["periods"]);
    periodStore.periods = everything.data["periods"];
    //END ON THE PART THAT HAS ISSUE
    
    eventStore.events = everything.data["events"];
    activityStore.activities = everything.data["activities"];
    bankStore.banks = everything.data["banks"];
    personStore.persons = everything.data["persons"];
    participationStore.participations = everything.data["participations"];
    cassetteOperationStore.cassetteOperations =
      everything.data["cassetteOperations"];
    bankOperationStore.bankOperations = everything.data["bankOperations"];
    console.log("initially logged");
  } else {
    console.log("initially not logged");
  }
}

fetchEverything();
```

I marked the line involved in the issue

The api function in laravel is like this

```
public function index(){
        $result=[];
        //get the current period to filter other collections
        $period=Period::where('current',1)->get();
        $start=$period[0]->start;
        $end=$period[0]->end;


        $periods=PeriodResource::collection(Period::all());
        $persons=PersonResource::collection(Person::all());
        $banks=BankResource::collection(Bank::all());
        //get events of the period only
        $events=EventResource::collection(Event::where('date','>=',$start)->where('date','<=',$end)->get());
        $activities=ActivityResource::collection(Activity::all());
        $participations=ParticipationResource::collection(Participation::all());
        //get cassette and bank operations for the period only
        $cassetteOperations=CassetteOperationResource::collection(CassetteOperation::where('date','>=',$start)->where('date','<=',$end)->get());
        $bankOperations=BankOperationResource::collection(BankOperation::where('date','>=',$start)->where('date','<=',$end)->get());

        //return everything
        $result['periods']=$periods;
        $result['persons']=$persons;
        $result['banks']=$banks;
        $result['events']=$events;
        $result['activities']=$activities;
        $result['participations']=$participations;
        $result['cassetteOperations']=$cassetteOperations;
        $result['bankOperations']=$bankOperations;

        return $result;

    }
```

As you can see in the javascript marked lines the periodStore.periods should receive the everything.data["periods"] .

It does but wrongly. In fact the last object in everything.data['periods'] is lost as you can see in the store state

[image]

According to the browser tools it seems that the return is correct

[image]

But looking at the console output there is something weird.
The everything.data['period'] is presented as having 3 elements but the length displayed is only 2.

Nevertheless the network tab shows that the returned data is correct also

[image]

I cannot find what can explain this strange behavior.

I could add that when updating one period with CRUD form the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
await axios.get("api/everything").then((everything) => {
  console.log(everything);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like this. I understand why now.